# Instead of printing XML output, create XML file

Tags: xml, go

In this Go / Golang code, I am printing XML. But instead of doing that, how can I create an XML file with this output?

The reason I want to do this is that the XML output is quite large and instead of copying and pasting the output from the terminal, since it would take quite a long time to highlight it all, it would be best if it was written to an XML file.

Here is the code:

```
    fmt.Printf("<card>\n")
    fmt.Printf("<title>"%s"</title>\n", properties["/type/object/name"])
    fmt.Printf("https://usercontent.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image"%s"\n", id)
    fmt.Printf("<text>%s</text>\n", properties["/common/document/text"])
    fmt.Println("<facts>")
    for k, v := range properties {
        for _,value := range v {
            fmt.Printf("<fact property=\"%s\">%s</fact>\n", k, value)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("</facts>")
    fmt.Println("</card>")
```

Comment: Maybe I am not getting the question, but how about writing to a file with `fmt.Fprintf`?

Comment: That's the question. ) I wonder what's so hard about just redirecting output to a file via shell command, like 'goprog >> somefile.txt'

Comment: @Volker How does one write to a file using fmt.Fprintf ?

Comment: @raina77ow oh, I didn't even think about that.

Comment: @gomangomango just open a file using `os.Create`, and instead of `fmt.Println`, just use `fmt.Fprintf(myFile, ....)`

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer But will that print each line to a new file or add to the same file? Also can you post an answer showing me how to open a file with os.Create ?

Comment: @gomangomango First *please* have a look at the Go documentation yourself and *no* `fmt.Fprintf(file, ...)` will not print to a new file each time it is called. Create a file like this: `file, _ := os.Create("filename")` but you should handle the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments one can create a file using `os.Create()` like so:

```
file, _:=os.Create("file.extension")
```

file being the variable the file is assigned to.

Then one can continually write to the file using:

```
fmt.Fprintf(file, "text in file")
```